# Center NavBar content/links

Tags: html, css, navbar

I need to center the content-links in my navbar. This:

[image: bar]

I want the Home, About and Contact to be centered on the navbar.

Comment: you need to post the code you have so far

Comment: Could you share some code? text-align: center; on the right place could work....

Comment: HTML:
`<body>
    <h1><a class="headerhome" href="index.html">gavinw.ml</a></h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    <div class="hero">
    <h2>Gavin - Toasst</h2>
    <a href="http://twitter.com/gavinw_">@gavinw_</a>
           </div>
    <p id="footer">&copy; Gavin W 2016.</p>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: CSS:
CSS:
`ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #111;
}

.active {
    background-color:#4CAF50;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using float, you can set the `li` element to `display: inline-block` and add `text-align: center` on the `ul` element.

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
}
li {
    display: inline-block
}
```

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/bjwskbcu/